# Обязательно ли использовать .moveTo в Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

Есть простой код:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="imgCanvas" width="660" height="660" style="border: 2px solid black"></canvas>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    let _ctx = document.getElementById('imgCanvas').getContext('2d');
    _ctx.beginPath();
    _ctx.lineTo(30, 300);
    _ctx.lineTo(90, 300);
    _ctx.lineTo(120, 120);
    _ctx.closePath();
    _ctx.stroke();
    _ctx.fill();

    _ctx.beginPath();
    _ctx.lineTo(300, 390);
    _ctx.lineTo(600, 300);
    _ctx.lineTo(180, 120);
    _ctx.closePath();
    _ctx.stroke();
    _ctx.fill();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Обычный канвас, на котором нужно нарисовать два треугольника. Я читал что использование метода `moveTo()` обязательное, но и без него все нормально отрисовывается. Я не понимаю вродебы после первой фигуры условное "перо" осталось в позиции `(120, 120)` и при использовании метода `lineTo(300, 390)` должна отрисоваться линия из `(120,120)` в `(3000,390)`, но этого не происходит, почему и обязательное ли тогда использование `moveTo()` или оно носит рекомендательный характер?

Смысл самого moveTo() мне понятен. Мне непонятно почему эти две фигуры не слиплись ведь самогото moveTo() небыло.

Comment: оно то рисуется, но где находится начальная точка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем коде можно и без него. `beginPath()` позволяет инициализировать новый объект (типо старый - это другая ячейка памяти). Первый lineTo попросту передвигает к конечной координате, т к начального пути нет

но смысл его в этом:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="imgCanvas" width="660" height="660" style="border: 2px solid black"></canvas>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    let _ctx = document.getElementById('imgCanvas').getContext('2d');
    // наччинаем путь
    _ctx.beginPath();
    // даигаем к координате
    _ctx.moveTo(30, 300);
    // рисуем к координате
    _ctx.lineTo(90, 300);
    // рисуем к координате
    _ctx.lineTo(120, 120);
    // закрываем путь (автоматически дорисовываятся линия от точки move к конечной)
    _ctx.closePath();
    _ctx.moveTo(300, 390);
    // рисуем к координате
    _ctx.lineTo(600, 300);
    // рисуем к координате
    _ctx.lineTo(180, 120);
     // закрываем путь (автоматически дорисовываятся линия от точки move к конечной)
    _ctx.closePath();
    _ctx.stroke();
    //_ctx.fill();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: тогда откуда начинается рисование второй фигуры в моем коде? Как раз ваш вопрос где находится начальная точка?

Comment: ее нет, поэтому `lineTo` и ничего не рисует,  а прост опередвигает